# Hide keyboard when navigation bar is touched

Tags: ios

I have a `UITabBarController` with four related views. In one of these views there is a text view which leaves room only for the `navigationbar`: what I would like to do is to hide the keyboard when the `navigationbar` is touched. How can I do this? Should I override the `touchesBegan:` method of `UINavigationBar`?

**EDIT**

---

the best way I found to do this is adding a `UITapGestureRecognizer`

```
UITapGestureRecognizer* tapRecon = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]
                                    initWithTarget:self action:@selector(navigationBarTap:)];
tapRecon.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
[self.navigationController.navigationBar addGestureRecognizer:tapRecon];
```

which calls the method

```
- (void)navigationBarTap:(UIGestureRecognizer*)recognizer { 
     [self.view endEditing:YES]; 
}
```

Comment: You detect your touch ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
UITapGestureRecognizer* tapRecon = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]
                                    initWithTarget:self action:@selector(navigationBarTap:)];
tapRecon.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
[self.navigationController.navigationBar addGestureRecognizer:tapRecon];


- (void)navigationBarTap:(UIGestureRecognizer*)recognizer {
     [self.view endEditing:YES];

    // OR

    for (id view in self.view.subviews) {
        if ([view isKindOfClass:[UITextView class]] || [view isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]]) {
            [view resignFirstResponder];
        }
    }
}
```

May this will help u

Comment: its my pleasure I could help someone.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this swift extension to dismiss the keyboard when clicked outside. user may be clicked on the navigation bar or viewcontroller view.

Just call once **hideKeyboardWhenTappedAround()** in your UIViewController

```
extension UIViewController {
    func hideKeyboardWhenTappedOutsides() {
       let tap: UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(UIViewController.dismissKeyboard(_:)))
       tap.cancelsTouchesInView = false
       // On viewcontroller view
       view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
       // On navigationcontroller view
       self.navigationController?.view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
}

@objc func dismissKeyboard(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    view.endEditing(true)
    if let navController = self.navigationController {
        navController.view.endEditing(true)
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Within your touchesBegan method you could resignFirstResponder to make the keyboard disappear. Hope this helps, cheers Jim.

Answer (score 0):

not tested.
Add Tap gestures to UINavigationbar and action for gesture to resign responder.

```
 UITapGestureRecognizer *gestureRecognizer=[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(hideKeyboard)];
    gestureRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired=1;
    gestureRecognizer.cancelsTouchesInView = NO;
    [UInavigationbar addGestureRecognizer:gestureRecognizer];
    [gestureRecognizer release];
```

Action:

```
[Textfield resignfirstresponder]
```

Answer (score 0):

// this method will call before navigating to other view...

```
-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillDisappear:YES];
    [yourTextField resignFirstResponder];
}
```

// this will resign keyboard before navigating to other screen..

I hope this will help you.